# Accessing files from all Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Let's say i have 5 instances running on Elastic Beanstalk. 
These instances create cache files, something like /app/cache/{client}/data.cache to reduce database querying.

When cache expires by itself (via ttl), no problem.
But sometimes i need to force it to refresh, when certain events occurs (user updates his data).
Since this happens in app, it will only affect the current instance where the request was triggered, the other 4 instances will hold stale cache.

Cache mechanisms like redis or memcached are not an option for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem, as the instances do not know that the others 'exist'. You can try the following:

First, create an endpoint on the application that flushes the cache. This needs to be accessible from outside beanstalk (like an http endpoint). When the cache is flushed by a user action, you need to trigger a script that:

1: Queries all active instances on beanstalk
2: Fires the 'flush cache' script on the http endpoint for all instances that were returned

You can do this inside the application. The AWS SDK has an API call to return all active instances in beanstalk. You need to find the load balancer corresponding to the beanstalk instance and then execute the `describeLoadBalancers` API call. Then you get the instance IDs which you can then use to get their IP addresses with another API call from the EC2 API.